# Why is this in my dryer? Can/Should I remove it?

Tags: dryer

2 year old Kenmore 600 series dryer; 1st time maintenance.
Is this supposed to be here?
It is glued to the side, which makes me think yes. It also came loose and clearly burned which is troubling.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have a gas dryer, and if it is insulation that is, or was glued in, it needs to stay. Most likely the insulation is non flammable and it keeps other flammable items from catching fire.

Comment: Totally agree with @Jack was going to say the same thing or close, why do some even question parts that's are glued in!!! + wish I could give more Jack.

Answer (score 1):

In olden days, something like that would have been asbestos, but asbestos has been banned since the 70s. The substitute materials (often called "mineral wool") are not quite as fire resistant, hence the char marks, but it's not going to actually catch on fire. I would glue it back where it was, using something that can withstand high temperatures. Go to a good hardware store and ask for a high temperature adhesive for flu insulation